# In Java, byte[] vs string as a method parameter have any pros/cons?

Tags: java, string, parameters, byte

I have a tab delimited file and I need to pass it around. I will be using BufferedReader to read lines. In that case does passing it as a byte[] vs String have any advantages and disadvantages.

If the file contains json data, would passing around as byte[] vs string have any advantages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. JSON should be a String, since it has an encoding and a meaning. `byte[]` is generally a physical, uninterpreted sequence of bytes; `String` is a sequence of characters.